Как поменять графическое окружение в дистрибутиве линукс, Ubuntu?
Я поставил себе Ubuntu 23.10 для эксперементов, первое что я хотел, это поменять графическое окружение с Unity (поправьте если это не так) на Cinnamon, так как наслышан, что линукс-дистрибутивы можно кастомить под себя по максимуму, так вот суть моего вопрос, как без переустановки системы, поменять графическое окружение через консоль
напишите пожалуйста для Cinnamon и XFCE, заранее спасибо!

https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/task-cinnamon-desktop https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/task-xfce-desktop

конечно спасибо, но что с этим дальше делать

например, установить эти два пакета.

а дальше то что

а дальше выбрать нужную графическую сессию при логине.

воу, спасибо, не знал что это так легко

Для Cinnamon : Установка Cinnamon в Ubuntu выполняется очень просто потому что пакет есть в официальных репозиториях. Перед установкой оболочки обновите все пакеты в системе:# apt update && apt full-upgrade. После :# apt install cinnamon-desktop-environment.После завершения установки перезагрузите компьютер или завершите текущий сеанс. В окне входа вы сможете выбрать сессию Cinnamon нажав на специальную шестеренку внизу.
Для XFCE : все тоже очень просто - сначала обновляем систему : # apt update && apt full-upgrade, далее : apt install xfce4. После установки Xfce необходимо выбрать его в качестве основного десктопа опять-таки нажав на шестеренку при запуске.

sudo apt install tasksel
sudo tasksel

Там будет меню, поставьте галочку

